# "Appendix" before appendix letter missing

Tags: overleaf, letters, appendix

I am writing a report where the chapters have a letter. I have a custom document class \documentclass[11pt]{tudelft-report} and the formatting of the titles is as follows. The appendices are now also called A | "appendix name" and I would prefer Appendix A | "appendix name". Can someone help me with this? [image]

```
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{2\baselineskip}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}

%% Format the section titles and spacing
\titleformat{\section}
    {\LARGE\titlestyle\bfseries}
    {\thesection}
    {5pt}
    {}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{4pt}

%% Format the subsections titles and spacing
\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\Large\titlestyle\bfseries}
    {\thesubsection}
    {5pt}
    {}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{2pt}

%% Format the subsubsections titles and spacing
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
    {\large\titlestyle\bfseries}
    {}
    {0pt}
    {}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{\bigskipamount}{0pt}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Search here for `appendix titlesec` or just link to one of the related questions (right column).